# How does Wigner rotation manifest itself in 3-forces?

Tags: special-relativity

There is no gravity. Two lasers, one in $(x, 0, 0)$ and the other in $(-x, 0, 0)$, are motionless. Both of them are pointing upward (in z direction) toward circumference of a motionless disk. The disk will start moving upward in z direction, if we turn lasers on, due to the force $Fs$ exerted by the poynting vectors. Since the lasers are assumed to be the same, disk cannot experience torque, or any kind of rotation for that matter.

Now, assume that the disk is bounded to move in z direction only and two lasers are rotating on circumference of a circle placed on xy plane (with radius $x$ and center of $(0, 0, 0)$) with constant speed. If we turn them on, again due to the symmetry of the system, disk starts moving upward without rotation; according to lab observer (S) who is at the rest with respect to disk at $t=0$. We want to know the force $Fr$ exerted by one of the lasers on disk from S point of view. To do this, we can consider an inertial frame $S'$ which is momentarily at the rest with respect to one of lasers and use Lorentz transformation matrix on 4-force of $S'$ to get $Fr$. According to $S'$, poynting vector's force of the laser is $Fs$, because after all, it is motionless in this frame. So we have

$$F' = (0, 0, 0, Fs)^T$$
$$F = \Lambda(vx,vy,0) F'$$

Where $vx$ and $vy$ are velocity of $S'$ in $S$ viewpoint and $\Lambda(vx,vy,0)$ is *pure* boost matrix given by

$$ \Lambda(vx, vy, 0) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}] & -\frac{\text{vx} \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & -\frac{\text{vy} \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & 0 \\
 -\frac{\text{vx} \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & \frac{\text{vx}^2 \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]+\text{vy}^2}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2} & \frac{\text{vx} \text{vy} (\gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-1)}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2} & 0 \\
 -\frac{\text{vy} \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & \frac{\text{vx} \text{vy} (\gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-1)}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2} & \frac{\text{vy}^2 \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]+\text{vx}^2}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

So of course $F = F'$ but since we are interested in $Fr$ (z component of 3-force) we can simply use the fact that

$$f = \frac{(0, 0, Fs)^T}{\Lambda_{11}} = (0, 0, Fs/\gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}] )^T$$

So $Fr = Fs/\gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]$, which is expected, since due to the rotational Doppler shift (or rather, the change of electric and magnetic field magnitudes) force of lasers decreases. However, the force of both lasers are the same, so net torque is zero.

Assume another observer S'' who moves in x direction with velocity $ux$ with respect to S. Again, we are interested in z component of 3-force of S''. This time however, since S'' and S' axis are not collinear, we have to consider Wigner rotation. Simply put, since S' and S are connected by $\Lambda(vx, vy, 0)$ and S'' and S are connected via $\Lambda(ux, 0, 0)$ we can say that S'' and S' are connected by

$$F'' =  \Lambda'F'=\Lambda(-ux,0,0) \Lambda(vx,vy,0) F'$$

which again gives $F'' = F'$ but for three force we have

$$f' = \frac{(0, 0, Fs)^T}{\Lambda'_{11}}=\frac{(0, 0, Fs)^T}{\gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-\frac{u \text{vx} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c^2}}$$

Or
$$Fr'' = \frac{Fs}{\gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-\frac{u \text{vx} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c^2}}$$

Now, here is the problem. Under appropriate coordinate transformation $vx = -rwsin(wt)$ and $vy = rwcos(wt)$ we can immediately see that $Fr = \sqrt{1-r^2w^2/c^2}Fs$ but

$$Fr'' = \frac{\sqrt{1-r^2w^2/c^2}\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2} Fs}{(1 + \frac{u \ r \ w \ \sin(wt)}{c^2})}$$

Note that all unprimed coordinates belong to S. The last equation makes me uncomfortable, because it is time dependent; meaning, depending on the location of lasers, their force changes. If we attach a few sensors on circumference of the disk for measuring force of lasers in z direction, according to S'' their value should change through time, periodically. While S argues that force is not time dependent, and S'' claim is not true. One might argue that the mechanism of sensors change from S'' point of view, which is true. But this change will not and cannot be time dependent, since S and S'' are connected via  $\Lambda(u, 0, 0)$. So, where is the problem?

P.S: This question was inspired from an article cited here [Thought experiment and possible contradiction between kinematics and dynamics in special relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685215/thought-experiment-and-possible-contradiction-between-kinematics-and-dynamics-in) but I understood neither the article fully, nor the question of the author. I came up with my own version with simpler formalism.

Edit 1: If you are not comfortable with sensors and measuring forces, you can consider this: S can apply constant force $Fo = -Fr$ to disk, to keep its velocity constant. On the other hand, according to S'' we have $Fo''=-Fr/\gamma(u, 0, 0)$ which cannot cancel time dependent force of $Fr''$.

Edit 2: In the case anyone wondering how $\Lambda'$ looks like, it is like this:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-\frac{u \text{vx} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c^2} & \frac{u \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \left(\text{vx}^2 \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]+\text{vy}^2\right)}{c \left(\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2\right)}-\frac{\text{vx} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & \frac{u \text{vx} \text{vy} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] (\gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-1)}{c \left(\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2\right)}-\frac{\text{vy} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & 0 \\
 \frac{u \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c}-\frac{\text{vx} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & \frac{\gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \left(\text{vx}^2 \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]+\text{vy}^2\right)}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2}-\frac{u \text{vx} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c^2} & \frac{\text{vx} \text{vy} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] (\gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-1)}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2}-\frac{u \text{vy} \gamma [\{-u,0,0\}] \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c^2} & 0 \\
 -\frac{\text{vy} \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]}{c} & \frac{\text{vx} \text{vy} (\gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]-1)}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2} & \frac{\text{vy}^2 \gamma [\{\text{vx},\text{vy},0\}]+\text{vx}^2}{\text{vx}^2+\text{vy}^2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I omitted this matrix from original post since I thought knowing its full form is useless, but I changed my mind. Of course, none of calculations was done by hand, it was done by Mathmatica (that's where those redundant curly brackets come from) so unless there is a problem with my logic, matrices should be fine. Moreover, I extracted 3-force from 4-force according to this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(special_relativity), knowing that the first element of $\Lambda'$ represents $\gamma''$ since if $\Lambda'$ acts on four velocity of $S'$, the coefficient of first element of the four velocity represents $\gamma''$ which in this case is $\Lambda'_{11}$.